# Is apt-get update and upgrade necessary?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

If I've already executed both `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, do I need to do the same with `apt-get`?

Comment: No, it is the same thing.

Comment: no, apt-get is just simply reduced to apt in 16.04

Comment: @luv.preet In terms of typing apt is reduced because it saves typing 4 characters, but in terms of functionality apt is increased because it has additional features that apt-get doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt` and `apt-get` use the same repository configurations.

So `apt update` and and `apt-get update` will do the same with the same repository

[More info - apt-vs-apt-get-ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/apt-vs-apt-get-ubuntu/)